# ngx-toastr ToastrService.show() type parameter Angular 2 +

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-toastr, ngtoast

I can use `ToastrService.success/error/warning/info()` without problem,

but when i use `ToastrService.show()` i don't know which correct string type i should send

i tried send a enum like this:

```js
export enum ToastType {
    Success = 'success',
    Error = 'error',
    Info = 'info',
    Warning = 'warning'
}
```

but the component lose the styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stumbled into the same issue and found the types at the docs:

```
iconClasses = {
  error: 'toast-error',
  info: 'toast-info',
  success: 'toast-success',
  warning: 'toast-warning'
};
```

Source:
https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#iconclasses-defaults

**UPDATE**

The show() method takes four parameters, where the type are the names listed above.

```
ToastrService.show(message?: string, title?: string, override?: Partial<IndividualConfig>, type?: string)
```

An example with all parameters can be seen here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uu7r6s

Or an even more complete example:
https://github.com/grabowskidaniel/exemplo-ngx-toastr

**Using NgxToastr version 10**

Answer (score 1):

I use ToasterService like this,

```
this._toasterService.openToast("", "update success!", "success");

this._toasterService.openToast("", "update error!", "error");
```